# Get selected words in mac and store them

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

For example, I look up apple. But the dictionary gives the explanation of apple.

I want to do two things at the same time that I look it up.

1. Find the word pronunciation.
2. Record the word I looked up.

[Google search for "apple"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWKtt.png)

Comment: Yes, Applescript will do this.

Comment: But I also want to make spoken dictionary and store the words I have looked up. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Please edit your question, add your code, and explain what you've tried.